# Edit group content in python regular expression MatchObject

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the following (simplified) code - this is the essence of what i would like to do

```
def replace_todo(m):
    m[2] = '*' if value else ' '
    return m.group()
```

I want to edit a specific group in the match object, and then render the whole match out including the edited part.

The replace_todo function gets called on every match by using

```
myCompiledRegex.sub(replace_todo, text)
```

The text that is used as input is

```
[ ] mah lalalalalaa
[*] mah lalalalalaa
```

expected output

```
[*] mah lalalalalaa
[*] mah lalalalalaa
```

The regex looks like this

```
^(\[( |\*)]) ([a-z][a-z][a-z]) (.*)$
```

But it seems i'm not allowed to edit the match object

When i try to execute the above code i get the following TypeError

```
_sre.SRE_Match&#39; object does not support item assignment
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

Using spicavigo solution, when converting the list to a string (str(groups)) this is how it looks

```
[u’[ ]’, '*’, u’jsp’, u’do something’]
```

this is how it should look

```
[*] jsp do something
```

Comment: Please could you include in your question: (1) the actual regex; (2) one or two examples of actual inputs along with expected outputs.

Comment: Done :) But it isn't really that relevant, all i need is a way to edit a single group of the matches, and then output the entire match :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am novice when it comes to regex but couldn't you take m.groups() initially, change whatever you wish to and then return the variable?

Say:

```
x=list(m.groups()) #NOTE: groups and not group
x[2] = '*' if value else ' '
return x
```

EDIT

Maybe now I get what you are trying to achieve. As mentioned in the comment below, can you change your regex to

```
'^(\[)( |\*)(]) ([a-z][a-z][a-z]) (.*)$'
```

This is basically to help in joining of the list m.groups()

Comment: ohh bucka, that introduced another problem

Comment: This won't work because the groups are not ordered exactly how it should be rendered, basicly what i need is a way to change the values in the match object, so that i can call the group() function and have it output the modified input. If i just join the list items together, il end up with this "[ ]*xxxremember stuff" but i need this "[*] xxx remember stuff"

Comment: Try changing your regex to this

'^(\[)( |\*)(]) ([a-z][a-z][a-z]) (.*)$'

Comment: That works :) I added parantheses around the two spaces to include those too. I wish i could just use the matchobject, but this works aswell. Thanks! :)